# How to affect background brightness based on camera rotation using OrbitControls.js

Tags: three.js, rotation, orientation

(Hello, it's my first ever post here)

here's what I'd like to incorporate in this [simple example](https://kubamatuszczak.com/example_gltf):

1. I would like to make the background turn from light to dark gradually when the user is closer to a particular orientation – *in this case (example above) the desired orientation is a steep angle so that the foreshortened anamorphic image looks like a regular skull* (the value of the background indicating the angle user should aim for – kind of like playing Hot and Cold)
2. when the user reaches the desired orientation (the background is then accordingly 100% dark) I would like it to lock rotation and trigger a video file in the background or a pop up window.

I assume it has to do with accessing the camera rotation values inside OrbitControls and setting some kind of an Event?? i have no idea how to access it.

Any kind of help, suggestions to edit the thread or explanation would be greatly appreciated, thank you so much in advance!

Comment: It seem's your issue is not only about orientation. The camera also has to be at a certain position otherwise the user does not see the skull, right?

Comment: That's a very good point but since i've disabled zooming and panning with

controls.enableZoom = false;
controls.enablePan = false;

as far as I undestand it's all limited to rotation now. Correct me if I'm wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `camera.position` to calculate the best vantage point. First, you have to figure out what the desired position is (I'm not sure how the wooden board is being placed, but this position seems to be close to: `{ x: 6.8, y: 0.6, z: -1.8}`)

```
var vantagePoint = new THREE.Vector3(6.8, 0.6, -1.8);
var distance = 100;
var normalized = 1;
var endColor = new THREE.Color(0xff9900);
var startColor = new THREE.Color(0x0099ff);
scene.background = startColor;

animate() {
   distance = vantagePoint.distanceTo(camera.position);
   normalized = THREE.Math.smoothstep(distance, 5, 100); // Converts [1, 100] => [0, 1]

   // Resets the color on each frame
   startColor.set(0x0099ff);
   startColor.lerp(endColor, normalized);
}
```

The closer to 0 you are, the closer you are to seeing the skull. You can then use that value to change the color of `scene.background`. Anything beyond 10 and you're 'cold', and you get hotter as you approach 0.

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.distanceTo

#### Update:

You can then transform the distance to a normalized value in the range of `[0, 1]` by using [`Math.smoothstep()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Math.smoothstep). Then interpolate the value of the colors with this normalized value using [`Color.lerp`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Color.lerp)

Comment: So the coordinates describe a point that "slides"(for the lack of better word or my understanding) on a sphere and since its orientation is always fixed (points towards the centre) that's all that i need to make it work? Right now the code is _var scene = new THREE.Scene(); 
scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xadadad );_  could you guide me what exactly to put there instead of the fixed hex in the parenthesis?? I've put the _distance = vantagePoint.distanceTo(camera.position);_ inside _function animate()_   Here's the updated the [example](https://kubamatuszczak.com/example_gltf)

Comment: Well, the camera orbits around the wooden plank kind of in a sphere, yes. What you're measuring is the distance from the camera to the desired position. See the updated answer above to see how you can use this distance to change the `scene.background` color.

Comment: I've updated the example but somehow I'm still not able to make it work.. If you could take a look at the codeI'd  greatly appreciate it, probably it's some rookie mistake or maybe it's the order i pasted the code? Anyway, thank you so much for the answer so far and sorry if I'm bothering you too much:)

Comment: My mistake, I left out an argument in the smoothstep function. It should be `smoothstep(distance, 5, 100);`, otherwise it's not doing anything. Keep in mind you're going to have to play with these `5, 100` values to get the desired behavior. You might end up with something closer to `0, 10`

Comment: That's sooolid, it works just like it was supposed to, you're the man!! Tweaked the values and `0.3, 2` seem like the perfect fit. Do you feel like tackling the second part of the question with locking the rotation and triggering something?

Comment: Glad that fixed your problem. Make sure you approve the answer so others can also benefit from it! :)